# Proper way to express application-specific exceptions

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to find a good way to express exceptions in dynamic-typed languages (e.g. Python, although the same code can be used with e.g. enums in static-typed languages). In my application, the exception is not going to be displayed to the user. Which one would be best? (or you can propose better)

```
def parseData(data):
    length = unpack('!L', data[0:4])
    if 4 + len(data) != length:
```

Option 1:

```
raise Exception("Invalid length")
```

Option 2:

```
return -1
# Some code later...
parseResult = parseData(data)
if validationResult == -1:
    # Do something with the error.
```

The point is that when user doesn't see the exception, is it worth the hassle of making custom exception types instead of coming the easy path and returning integer values? (this is often done in functions like .indexOf(...)).

Comment: Is this Python specific? Why is this tagged `Java` and `C#`? There is a `language-agnostic` tag if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only comment on Python, but I would only extremely rarely `raise Exception`, as it makes error handling much harder; `except Exception` would catch many legitimate errors I would much rather hear about.

Instead, I would `raise` something more meaningful from the [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html):

```
raise ValueError("Invalid length.")
```

Most of Python's built-in classes and functions would `raise` an exception rather than `return`ing some flag value. The only exception I can immediately think of is `str.find`, which will `return -1` if the sub-string can't be found (its partner `str.index` *will* `raise ValueError`; I find this preferable, as `-1` is a valid index).

There may be the occasional case where a single function could raise one of a range of exceptions, depending on what exactly has happened, but this is unusual - if your response will depend on what went wrong, that logic should probably be *inside* the function. You can still stick to the built-ins, for example:

```
def divide(n, lst, index):
    return n / lst[index]
```

could raise `TypeError`, `IndexError` or `ZeroDivisionError`, and I can deal with that accordingly:

```
try:
    divide(1, {3: 4, 5: 6}, 2)
except TypeError:
    ...
except IndexError:
    ...
except ZeroDivisionError:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print("Didn't see that coming: {0}".format(repr(e)))
```

You can even inspect the message in the exception to differentiate, if necessary:

```
def test():
    test()

try:
    test()
except RuntimeError as e:
    if "recursion" in e.args[0]
        print("Ran out of stack.")
    else:
        print("That was unexpected: {0}".format(repr(e)))
```